# Validar resultado de consulta sea igual a un carater

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

estoy realizando un proyecto de Login, y lo que quiero hacer es que si es un usuario entre a lado y si es admin entre a otro, ya estoy validando el usuario y password pero tengo en mi BD el campo tipo_usuario que es A si es admin y U si es usuario, quiero saber si el resultado de mi consulta lo puedo comparar con la letra "A" y si es verdad que me mande a el sitio indicado. Anexo el codigo para ver que tengo mal. Tengo poco programando en php asi que comprendan estas preguntas tan absurdas para algunos.

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');

session_start();
      $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$usr,$pw,$basedatos);
      if ($mysqli -> connect_errno)
      {
        printf("Conexion Fallida: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
      }
      if (isset($_POST["usuario"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
      {
        $username = $_POST['usuario'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $user = "SELECT tipo_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '" . $_POST['usuario'] ."'" . "AND contrasena = '" . $_POST['password'] ."'";
        $resultado1 = $mysqli -> prepare($user);
        $resultado1 -> execute();
        $resultado1 -> store_result();

        if ($resultado ->num_rows == "A")
        {
              $_SESSION['login'] = true;
              $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
              $_SESSION['start'] = time();
              $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (30 * 60);
              echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['usuario'];
              echo "<br><br><a href=panel_control.php>Panel de Control</a>";
      }
      else { 
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=usuario_noexiste.php'>";
          } 
    }
      $mysqli -> close();
?>
```

Comment: Tu variable se llama `$resultado1`, pero estas chequeando por `$resultado`.

Comment: si pongo $resultado1 me sale el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Safety\validar_usuario.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Safety\validar_usuario.php on line 21

Answer (score 0):

Mira ver si asi te funciona:

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');

session_start();
      $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$usr,$pw,$basedatos);
      if ($mysqli -> connect_errno)
      {
        printf("Conexion Fallida: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
      }
      if (isset($_POST["usuario"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
      {
        $username = $_POST['usuario'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $user = "SELECT tipo_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '" . $_POST['usuario'] ."'" . "AND contrasena = '" . $_POST['password'] ."'";
        $resultado1 = $mysqli -> prepare($user);
        $resultado1 -> execute();
        $datos = $resultado1 -> get_result();
        if($datos->num_rows > 0){
            $fila = $datos->fetch_assoc();
            if($fila['tipo_usuario'] == 'A'){
                $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                  $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
                  $_SESSION['start'] = time();
                  $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (30 * 60);
                  echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['usuario'];
                  echo "<br><br><a href=panel_control.php>Panel de Control</a>";
            } else {
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=usuario_noexiste.php'>";
            }
        }
    }
      $mysqli -> close();
?>
```

Cambie un poco la parte donde ejecutas la consulta use `get_result` en vez de store_result y con fetch_assoc obtengo las filas que me devuelve la consulta como un arreglo asociativo y ya ahi puedo preguntar por el tipo de usuario

Comment: Es verdad, dejame probar el codigo